# ¿Cómo importar un sólo componente de Boostrap en un archivo HTML?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, carrusel

Estoy habituado a importar en `frameworks` como `React` o `Vue.js` componentes aislados de librerías como `Boostrap` tipo: `import { Carousel } from...` etc. 
¿Pero como hacer esto en un proyecto simple de HTML + CSS + JavaScript?

Básicamente sólo quiero añadir una funcionalidad `carousel` a mi archivo `HTML`, y no quiero que `Boostrap` me toque nada más de la pagina (cuando meto el `CDN` aunque lo ponga por encima del `link.css` en el que trabajo, me sigue sobrescribiendo estilos muchas veces).

Echando un ojo a la documentación pone como llamar al `carousel` pero no me queda claro que tengo que descargar: `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/` para que funcione.

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En proyectos de HTML5, es más sencillo trabajar con el framework de Bootstrap que con otras librerías, básicamente bastaría con copiar las clases respectivas del componente `carousel`, en este caso.

Además se deben añadir dos librerías: Bootstrap.js y jQuery (esta última [es obligatoria para que funcione la primera](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js)). También cabe mencionar, que Bootstrap trabaja con la [versión *Slim Build* de jQuery](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/), aunque la versión completa es igualmente funcional. Las librerías de `Popper.js` y `Tooltip.js` no son necesarias.

En su documentación, puedes encontrar [las clases que necesita el componente](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#how-it-works), una vez conocidas estas, basta con ubicarlas en [su hoja de estilos](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css) y trasladarlas a tu proyecto.

Te dejé en el ejemplo el componente con [la mayoría de sus opciones posibles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#with-captions); recuerda que los `captions` no se harán visibles en pantallas inferiores a 768px debido a la clase [`.d-md-block`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements).

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel.pointer-event {
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner::after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel-item {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-left),
.active.carousel-item-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-right),
.active.carousel-item-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-right {
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0s 0.6s opacity;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-right {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 15%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel-control-prev,
  .carousel-control-next {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.carousel-control-prev:hover,
.carousel-control-prev:focus,
.carousel-control-next:hover,
.carousel-control-next:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  right: 0;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: no-repeat 50% / 100% 100%;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel-indicators li {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.d-none {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .d-md-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 0;
}

.sr-only-focusable:active,
.sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="bd-example">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

PD: Las clases relativas a `.carousel-fade` hacen referencia al componente con la opción de [*Crossfade*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#crossfade). Si no la deseas usar, puedes eliminarlas del CSS.